# Dom loaded event cross borwser native javascript code

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm working without the JavaScript framework, but I want to call a function just when the DOM is loaded.

I can't/don't want to use the attribute `onload` on the  `<body>` tag.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/732801/how-to-verify-if-a-webpage-is-completely-loaded-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

- in non-IE browsers, use DOMContentLoaded event
- in IE top frame use scroll hack (see _readyIEtop)
- in IE frame, simply use onload

  ```
  var onready = function(handler) {
      // window is loaded already - just run the handler
      if(document && document.readyState==="complete") return handler();

      // non-IE: DOMContentLoaded event
      if(window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",handler,false);

      // IE top frame: use scroll hack
      else if(window.attachEvent && window==window.top) { if(_readyQueue.push(handler)==1) _readyIEtop(); }

      // IE frame: use onload
      else if(window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload",handler);
  };

  // IE stuff
  var _readyQueue = [];
  var _readyIEtop = function() {
      try {
        document.documentElement.doScroll("left");
        var fn; while((fn=_readyQueue.shift())!=undefined) fn();
      }
      catch(err) { setTimeout(_readyIEtop,50); }
  };
  ```

jQuery tunes the IE a little more (lots of code), but in my tests it runs just before onload event anyway.

```
var test = function() { alert("ok"); }
onready(test);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you say me if none of these work, aren't you sure of your answer, in more you say mae use onload???? did you rode my question?

Comment: pardon my english: by "if none of these works" I mean "if it's not the case" - see the comments in my code. I have tested it here - http://jsfiddle.net/yCLZL/

Answer (score 3):

I think http://code.google.com/p/domready/ is exactly what you're looking for.

> If you are ever writing your own JavaScript file that cannot depend on
>   the existing libraries out there and would like to execute only after
>   the page is loaded, this library is for you.
>
> Simply do this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <script src="domready.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript">
                DomReady.ready(function() {
                    alert('dom is ready');
                });
        </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you it sound perfect, I will try, seems as Graham answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm afraid cross-browser and DOM loaded don't go together easily. By recommendation is Ryan Morr's **ondomready** (https://github.com/ryanmorr/ondomready) but there are a ton of alterntives.