# Bind datetime javascript to table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had html table with 31 rows and 4 table columns I am trying to write javascript(Jquery)  to bind first column with dates of the current  month.

This is my code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function ($) {
                var table = document.getElementById("myTable")
                var myDate = new Date();
                myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 1)
                for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                    var row = document.createElement("tr");
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    cell.innerText = myDate.getDate() + "/" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getYear();
                    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1)
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                    table.tBodies[0].appendChild(row);
                }
            });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<table id="myTable"></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: plz describe more with code what you want to do and where you face problem.

Comment: but you can try this  `$('table tr').each(function() {
  // need this to skip the first row
  if ($(this).find("td:first").length > 0) {
     $(this).find("td:first").html(new Date());
  }
});`

Comment: how can there be a 500 bounty by a questioner who has less than that in points?

Comment: @abbood He can give out a 500 bounty with 638 rep.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question, but I've created the JSFiddle for those who do understand. http://jsfiddle.net/nLQ7q/

Comment: Either I did not understand the question or people are over complicating things due to bounty. In my answer I did it with 6 lines of code what people are trying to do with god knows what.

Comment: You've already got 9 answers to 0 question but first thing is first: www.jquery.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your question is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222137/adding-jquery-ui-datepicker-dynamically-style-break).
In other words, you are looking for a Javascript function that should add to an empty table one row for each day of the current month; each row should have four columns named "Date", "Start Time", "End Time" and "Hour Type" and the first column ("Date") should contain a text input with a date in the format "dd/mm/yyyy".
If so, here is my solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881938/javascript-calculate-number-of-days-in-month-for-a-given-year
        Date.prototype.daysInMonth = function(year, month) { 
            var monthStart  = new Date(year, month, 1);
            var monthEnd    = new Date(year, month + 1, 1);
            var monthLength = Math.round((monthEnd - monthStart) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var mm  = ((month + 1) < 10) ? ('0' + (month + 1)) : (month + 1);
            var ret = new Array();
            for (var i = 1; i <= monthLength; i++) {
                var dd = (i < 10) ? ('0' + i) : i;
                ret.push(dd + '/' + mm + '/' + year);
            }
            return ret;
        };

        function addRows(table, dates) {
            var idx = 1;
            for (var i in dates) {
                table.append('<tr>'+
                             '<td><input name="date'+idx+'" id="date'+idx+'" class="date" value="'+dates[i]+'"></td>'+
                             '<td><input name="startTime'+idx+'" id="startTime'+idx+'"></td>'+
                             '<td><input name="endTime'+idx+'" id="EndTime'+idx+'"></td>'+
                             '<td>'+
                             '<select name="hourType'+idx+'" id="hourType'+idx+'">'+
                             '<option value="">Please select</option>'+
                             '<option value="1">Regular</option>'+
                             '<option value="2">Overtime</option>'+
                             '</select>'+
                             '</td>'+
                             '</tr>');
                idx++;
            }
        }

        $(function() {
            var myDate = new Date();
            var year   = myDate.getFullYear();
            var month  = myDate.getMonth(); 
            var dates  = myDate.daysInMonth(year, month);
            var table  = $("#myTable").find("tbody");
            addRows(table, dates);
        });
        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
          <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <th>Hour Type</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Obviously, the table may also have less than 31 rows, depending on the number of days of the current month.

Comment: @Sedz Thank you for the tip; I've updated my answer as suggested

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that also breaks the loop in case we're dealing with a shorter month (e.g. in April, the table will *not* display 31/4/2013):

```
$(function() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable")
    var myDate = new Date();
    var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var firstOfMonth = new Date();
    firstOfMonth.setDate(1);
    for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++) {
        myDate.setDate(firstOfMonth.getDate() + i);
        if (myDate.getMonth() + 1 != month) break;
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.innerText = formatDate(myDate, dateFormat);
        row.appendChild(cell);
        table.tBodies[0].appendChild(row);
    }
});
```

[**Link to jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/MP4LR/9/)

Note: the OP mentions javascript as the 1st option (jQuery only in backets), that's why I left the code in plain js (with the exception of the DOM ready wrapper).
In case that you want a solution that fully independent of jQuery, bind the DOM content load event as described [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181061/dom-loaded-event-cross-borwser-native-javascript-code)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to append to the `tbody` but you didn't defined one. Change HTML to

```
<table id="myTable"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

And if you already have rows and cells, you want just to prepend the new cells

```
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    cell.innerText = myDate.getDate() + "/" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getFullYear();
                    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1)
                    $(table).find('tr').eq(i).prepend(cell);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/9fQxq/

Use

```
table.appendChild(row);
```

instead of

```
table.tBodies[0].appendChild(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/upeRf/1/).

The way I would use :

```
var d = new Date();              // get current date
var currentMonth = d.getMonth(); // save current month
d.setDate(1);                    // set date to first day of current month

// (...) create your table header

// create 31 rows
for(var i=1; i<=31; i++) {
    var line = $(document.createElement('tr'));
    if(d.getMonth() == currentMonth) {
        // add the date to the first column
        line.append('<td>'+dateToDMY(d)+'</td>')
            .append('<td></td>')
            .append('<td></td>')
            .append('<td></td>');
    } else {
        // in case you always want to have 31 rows, whatever the month
        line.append('<td colspan="4" class="empty">&nbsp</td>');
    }

    $('#myTable').append(line);  // append the line to the table
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);  // increase the date
}

/* 
 * Format Date : dd/mm/yyyy
 * Based on Adrian Maire work
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/10685571/1238019
*/
function dateToDMY(date) {
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    return '' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '/' + (m<=9 ? '0' + m : m) + '/' + y;
}
```

Note that using [setDate function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) will automaticaly update the date month with an out of range day (then you don't have to care about leap years)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly than you want to bind the first column with dates in current month? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2SeZ/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Get today date
    var d = new Date();
    //Get Days of Month
    var n = new Date(d.getYear(), d.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate();

    //Run loop for number of days
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        //Create row data
        var row = '<tr><td>'+ i + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear()+'</td><td><td/><td><td/><td><td/></tr>';

        // Append row data to table
        $('#myTable').append(row);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear.. but From your code what I understood is that you are creating table 16 rows in which column 1 has date from `(CURRENT_DATE - 1)` to `(CURRENT_DATE+14)`.

I used template to render table rows. Update the templates as you like to render other columns.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/nLQ7q/3/

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
     var table = $("#myTable")
     var myDate = new Date();
     myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 1);

     var rowTmpl = '<tr><td>{DATE}</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
     var rows = [];

     for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
         var row = rowTmpl.replace('{DATE}', myDate.getDate() + "/" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getYear());
         myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1)
         rows.push(row);         
     }

      table.html(rows.join(''));
 });
```

---

A little bit fancy version here with a date picker http://jsfiddle.net/nLQ7q/4/

Answer (score 0):

#### You can tryout this: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nRfS2/)

`<table id="myTable"></table>`

Mind it, you don't have `tbody` in your markup, so i put that and used the below jquery

#### `-JQUERY-`:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     var table = $("#myTable");
     var myDate = new Date();
     myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 1)
     for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        var row = $("<tr>");
        var cell = $("<td>");
        myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1)
        cell.text(myDate.getDate() + "/" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getFullYear());
        row.append(cell);
        table.find('tbody').append(row);
    }
    $('#myTable').find('tr').each(function (i, v) {
       $(this).append('<td/><td/><td/>');
       $('td:not(:first)', this).text(i + 1);
    });
 });
```

At each `row in the tr` filled `first td` with dates and `created other tds` with some default text.

#### I have comeup with this : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nRfS2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function ($) {
     var table = $("#myTable")
     var myDate = new Date();

     myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() - 1);

     for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++)
     {
         var row = $('<tr/>');         
         var cell = $('<td/>');

         cell.text
          (myDate.getDate() +
           "/" +
           (myDate.getMonth() + 1) +
           "/" +
           (1900 + myDate.getYear()));

         myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 1);

         row.append(cell);
         table.append(row);
     }
 });
```